# this.props is duplicating to the next component sometimes bug [weird bug]

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of different components:

```
   const [items, setItems] = useState([

    <CreateVideoCard onChange={cardActionResponse} onUpdate={cardUpdate}  />,
    <CreateAudioCard onChange={cardActionResponse} onUpdate={cardUpdate} ></CreateAudioCard>,
    <CreateDescriptionCard onChange={cardActionResponse} onUpdate={cardUpdate} ></CreateDescriptionCard>,
    <CreateDescriptionCard onChange={cardActionResponse} onUpdate={cardUpdate} ></CreateDescriptionCard>,
    <CreateTermsCard onChange={cardActionResponse} onUpdate={cardUpdate} ></CreateTermsCard>,
]);
```

When I drop a new component, its adds it to my list

```
items.splice(location, 0, card)
```

Each card has two functions I add to it. cardActionResponse & cardUpdate
They simply update the current card, or delete/duplicate. I've checked both of them and they don't seem to be the error.

When I rerender my components, sometimes the new Card had previous data from another card. (This.props) The card constructor checks if props is undefined.

```
if (props.data != undefined) {
            console.log(props.data)
            this.state = {
                url: props.data.url,
                urlValid: props.data.urlValid,
                videoFile: props.data.videoFile,
                question: props.data.question,
                description: props.data.description,
                options: props.data.options
            }
        } else {

            //Starter
            this.state = {
                url: null,
                urlValid: false,
                videoFile: false,

                question: '',
                description: '',
                options: [
                    {
                        title: '',
                        description: '',
                        price: null
                    },
                    {
                        title: '',
                        description: '',
                        price: null
                    },
                    {
                        title: '',
                        description: '',
                        price: null
                    }
                ]//End of options
            }
```

Right before I render it, I print out each Card's props I get:

```
0 undefined
1 [object Object]
2 undefined
3 undefined
4 undefined
5 undefined
```

What's weird is that sometimes its not undefined when its a new card which then uses previous data from another card.

In other words, card 0 has card 1 props for some reason.

I cant seem to explain this error. Does anyone know what's going on?

NEW ERROR

---

The error seems to be when I call super(props) as it uses the props from the previous component. When I render it, it's fine so the problem is within the constructor of a card.

Comment: Component instances should never be stored in state; they should be returned from your functional components but that's it. Values in state should be plain old JavaScript objects, numbers, arrays, etc.

Comment: Why's that? I was planning to store it into state, and send it to my backend (MongoDB) when a user presses save.

Comment: Are you mapping `items` to produce your render, and if so, what keys are you providing each component instance? The issue you're describing is often caused by using a non-unique key such as the map index (the default key).

Comment: Yes sir.    {items.map((item, i) => ( {React.cloneElement(item, { i: i })} </div> ))} . I clone each item to have it the unique index a.k.a i

Comment: What would it even mean to send the component to the backend? Presumably you need to serialize it to JSON first anyways. So why store the component in the state vs. some object that can easily be serialized as JSON?